# Probing the target board failed - Nividia TX2

Tags: flash, dji-sdk, nvidia-jetson

I am trying to flash the DJI Manifold 2G with the official DJI image. When I try to flash it using the command,

```
sudo ./flash.sh jetson-tx2 mmcblk0p1
```

the error appears:

```
###############################################################################
# L4T BSP Information:
# R28 (release), REVISION: 2.1, GCID: 11272647, BOARD: t186ref, EABI: aarch64, 
# DATE: Thu May 17 07:29:06 UTC 2018
###############################################################################
Error: probing the target board failed.
       Make sure the target board is connected through 
       micro-B USB port and is in recovery mode.
```

I have checked using "lsusb" command to make the sure the board is in recovery mode and it is as shown here"

```
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0b05:6208 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. C-Media(R) Audio
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13d3:3563 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 003 Device 021: ID 0955:7c18 NVIDIA Corp. T186 [TX2 Tegra Parker] recovery mode
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:56a2 IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I am also using a micro-USB B cable, and I have tried by attaching, detaching cable and even rebooting the system, it does not work. Could anyone help me out here please?

I am also using a micro-USB B cable, and I have tried by attaching, detaching cable and even rebooting the system, it does not work. Could anyone help me out here please?

Comment: For flashing L4T R28, you may try using an Ubuntu 16.04 host PC (not a VM). Some signal issue may also be raised depending on the hardware. You may try other cables, other connectors, inserting or removing a hub in between. Be sure the target is enough powered.